# How to compare parsed json value in C#

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I am a beginner in c# , I am creating a app in which login page requests PHP file in url and it sends Json data as response I was able to decode the Json data,But the decoded data was not able to use in string comparison as below

**Program**

```
 private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
 var username = usernames .Text;
 var password = passwords .Password;
 var postMessage = new StringContent(string.Format("username={0}&password={1}", username, password), Encoding.UTF8 , "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 var response = await (new HttpClient()).PostAsync("http://xxxxx.xx.xxx/xlogin.php", postMessage);
 var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 var jsonString = responseBody ;
        //remove "{" and "}" from sting
 var result = jsonString.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
        //separate property name from it's value
 var pair = result.Split(':');
        //property will contain property name : "result"
 var property = pair[0];
        //value will contain property value : "Invalid"
 var value = pair[1];
       // String van=value .ToString() ;
        MessageBox.Show(value);
 if(value=="Valid")
{
Messagebox.show("success");
}

else
{
   Messagebox.show("Error");
}                 
}
```

**Response from URL**
Json response from url is {"result":"Invalid"} while validation fails and for validation success {"result":"Valid"}

**Problem**
Every time I get "Valid" From url it is not accepting in if condition,more precisely string is not getting compared...any solutions?

Comment: Why are you trying to parse the JSON manually? There are plenty of good JSON libraries out there - I *strongly* suggest that you use one.

Comment: And since it contains small data I parsed manually

Comment: @vinod I would suggest [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json). Extremely easy to learn/use.

Comment: The size of the data doesn't make it a good idea to do this manually. Look at Json.NET or ServiceStack.Text for example.

Comment: use string value = pair[1].ToString(); instead of var value = pair[1];

Comment: @Jaihind: Why would you expect that to make any difference? `pair` is a `string[]`...

Comment: @JonSkeet var is used when storing a reference to an object of an anonymous type, but in this it obvious a string type.

Comment: @Jaihind: `var` doesn't have to be used for anonymous types. All it means is that the compiler infers the type. Using `var value = pair[1];` has *exactly* the same effect as `string value = pair[1];` in this case, and there's no need to call `ToString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the immediate problem is that your `pair[1]` value still starts and ends with a double quote - so if you print it out you'll see

```
"Value"
```

rather than

```
Value
```

You *could* just trim them from the start manually, but I would strongly advise you to use a JSON library instead. There's no good reason to do all of this manually, and trying to do so is very likely to lead to brittle code.

As an example, using [Json.NET](http://json.net) it's as simple as:

```
string json = "{\"result\":\"Valid\"}";
JObject parsed = JObject.Parse(json);
string result = (string) parsed["result"];
Console.WriteLine(result); // Prints Valid
```

Comment: You are right I am getting it like this "Value" How could I trim them

Comment: @vinod: There are lots of options (`string.Trim`, `string.Substring` etc) - but again, you *shouldn't do this manually*. Just use Json.NET or something similar - your code will be *much* simpler and more robust.

Comment: Okay...I will follow this practice..@jon Skeet

Comment: @vinod: See my edit for a simple example of using Json.NET. See how much simpler that is?

Comment: Impressed with Json.Net..Thank you ..@jon Skeet

Comment: If you dont mind Can you explain these two lines                                                         JObject parsed = JObject.Parse(json);
string result = (string) parsed["result"];

Comment: @vinod: Well have you read the documentation? Json.NET is pretty well documented - you need to do some research yourself.